# Prevent UICollectionView to scroll while inserting items on top

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In my iOS app I have a UICollectionView that updates its content dynamically from server. Let's suppose there are 10 cells (index 0-9) in UIollectionView, when i download other 10 object, i insert them at index (0-9), shifting old items to index (10-19).

My goal would be to invalidate UICollectionView animation so, if i had element at index 3 at the top position, when i add other 10 items, they're added as top items but i see again the same item showed previously (that after update will be at index 13).

I tried wrapping UICollectionView items insert in UIView.performWithoutAnimation method or using this code:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

// insert items in collection view using perform batch updates

UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

But result is still not good and my UICollectionView still scroll 'random' when i add items on top range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try but here's a list of things you can try :

- Setting `self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = false` before your update and `self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = true` right after
- Not sure but you can try to set `self.collectionView.scrollsToTop = false`
- Save current position of scrollView in a `CGPoint`, then right after your update call `self.collectionView.setContentOffset(previousPosition, animated: false)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Third approach seems good. I implemented it with a difference. I remember my last content offset, then i add all items and then i set content offset to rememberedContentOffset + addedItemsTotalHeight. It works, after insert i'm still looking at the remembered cell, but visual effect is very bad. It scrolls up during insert and then scroll down also if i have disabled all animations

Comment: Did you find a solution to avoid this side effect ?

Comment: Animation is not really perfect, but i've implemented some logics to make it works good. Something like save every cell height in an array and other performance improvements.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply modifying your data array and using `.reloadData` on your collectionView ?

It'll reload it all shouldn't do any scrolling. That means if you're at the bottom of a 30 element scrollview, it'll stay at the bottom.

But you can call right afterwards and it'll force a scroll to top with or without animation :

`collectionview.SetContentOffset(CGPoint.Zero, false);`

The line above is written from memory and probably wrong in its spelling. Basically, set a content offset of 0,0 using the method, not the property, and use the second parameter to remove animation.

Comment: I had already tried solutions provided in your link without success. I use performBatchUpdates, shouldn't i use it?

Comment: Actually you could do it another way ; take a look at my edited answer. Is using .reloadData okay in your scenario?

Comment: I've tried using reload data, but it scrolls anyway. I prefer to not use it too, since i'd like to reload only item inserted and maintain scroll position. I think that i'll have to make it scroll programmatically to the remembered position + (items added total height)